# Python smtplib: Unable to send email from gmail to yahoo due to TimeoutError and SMTPConnectError

Tags: python, email, smtp, smtplib, smtp-auth

The code keeps bringing the TimeoutError and I have shutoff my firewall, used app password and so on:

CODE:

```
import smtplib
my_email = 'xxxxxx@gmail.com'
password = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
connection = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com")
connection.starttls() 
connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="xxxxxxxxxx@yahoo.com", msg="Hello World!")
connection.close()
```

ERROR:

`TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond`

And when I add the port = 587 argument, it brings this error instead:

`smtplib.SMTPConnectError: (421, b'Service not available')`

Tried to use smtplib to send email from a gmail to a yahoo mail account. What I expected was a delivered message to the yahoo mail but I encountered this error instead.